# Are foreign drivers liable to pay fines proportional to their income when committing driving-related violations in Finland?

Tags: legal, driving, finland

In Finland, there is a [peculiar system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day-fine) (päiväsakko/dagsböter/day-fines) where drivers who commit violations on the road (such as speeding) are punished with a fine proportional to their income.

Does this system also apply to foreign non-resident drivers? Or do they pay some fixed amount since it's hard to determine what they earn abroad?

Comment: How could they enforce it? How could the Finnish police know about your income?

Comment: @Taladris I have no idea, which is why I ask

Comment: Enforcement of fines across the EU is now a possibility. How they actually set those is an interesting question, I will find it out.

Comment: http://yle.fi/uutiset/osasto/news/foreign_speeders_now_liable_for_finnish_fines/7734603   Check here also http://www.expat-finland.com/pdf/driving_in_finland.pdf  page 31. Suggests a flat fine for speeding.

Comment: @DumbCoder How do you read the brochure to 'suggest a flat fine for speeding'? It clearly states that fines for serious speeding offences or other traffic offences are calculated based on income.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I glanced over it and left it to you to read it in detail.

Comment: @Taladris The offender (also residents or citizens of Finland) is required to disclose their income and other circumstances required to caluclate the base of a day-fine. Failure to do so is punishable with up to three months imprisonment (Finish penal code, chapter 16. §6: fine fraud). I also assume that if they want to verify the information, Finnish authorities can at least for EU residents request information from the resident's home country.

Comment: Nothing peculiar with it. Calculating fine depending on income is quite normal in any penalty system I know. Only that most countries aren't eager to take matters into court for speeding.

Comment: I think you always have the choice between paying the fine and going to prison (at least in Germany), so if it happened to me and I want to save the money, and it happened to Bill Gates, we could share a cell for 14 days instead of paying 14 days income each, for example. So it's entirely fair.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should consult the [SpeedingEurope](http://www.speedingeurope.com/finland/) page to see the fines laid out in per-day amounts, where the lowest is 6 EUR / day. The police will work with that amount with a tourist, see this [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Finland/comments/5nj7cp/how_does_the_dagsb%C3%B6ter_system_work_for_tourists/dcby5ac/):

> The law says you're supposed to report your real income and the fine is based on that. In practise you'll get the minimum fine since there is no way to check if you're lying or not. Woudn't be suprised if they don't even bother asking anything.
>   A year or two ago some Finnish NHL player said to police that he's not earning anything and recieved minimum fine. The police later figured out who he really was and then charged him for lying. So it is possible to get caught and punished, but this probably doesn't affect your average tourist.

Comment: Nice work outsourcing this to Reddit 

Comment: Well, where do you find a Finn to answer this? :) And the SpeedingEurope site is my finding.

Comment: This may not apply to non EU nationals though..  As part of the visa application process you declare your income to the govt, and they may cross reference it from your visa application.